# How to disable interaction animations on line chart but keep tooltips?

Tags: highcharts

I can get rid of all animations with this

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    enableMouseTracking: true
```

But I want tooltips. But I don't want any other mouseover effects. I tried this suggestion:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    allowPointSelect: false,
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      },
      inactive: {
        enabled: false
      },
      select: {
        enabled: false
     }
    }
  }
},
```

But it has no effect on animations. My series are still faded if I mouseover an area with null data.

Comment: Related to this? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13518. But I am not seeing any change when I flip styledMode between true and false.

Comment: Could you please reproduce your example to the working demo? I've tried to test it but in my case, everything works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d0584jvk/

Comment: I am working on adding a working demo. But I do observe that adding to series:

    .highcharts-series-inactive {
      opacity: 1 !important;
    }

removes the hover animation of fading.

Comment: @magdalena. I made this fiddle. All I did was add the css reference. https://jsfiddle.net/intrasight/ecxoasgu/2/

Comment: Note that if I uncomment the "opacity:1" setting then it's back to how yours was. But styledMode=false and thus the CSS should be used - according to my reading of the docs.

Comment: Hi, when you don't use styledmode, you don't have to add the default CSS file. Styled Mode separates graphic design from the chart functionality -  all presentational attributes provided by API are disabled then, and adding a CSS file is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up:

- when `styledmode` is turn on, and you loading default CSS file, you need to add following code to the CSS:

```css
inactive { opacity: 1 }
```

- when `styledmode` is disabled (by default), you don't need to add the default CSS file, but to achieve that use options provided by API:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        },
        inactive: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```